# How to add a compile-time global variable in webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I've got a dynamically configurable webpack setup, with some custom loaders. Each of these loaders needs a configuration object which is only known dynamically, at compile time, so it's not possible to hard code it in loader's `options`. How can loaders access this object? Is there a "canonical" way to have a compile-time global in webpack?

Basically, my setup allows for multiple dynamic build-time configurations, it looks like this:

```
// webpack.config.js

let defaults = {
   ....
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: '.some.special.stuff',
                loader: 'my-own-loader',
            }
}

module.exports = function main() {
    let BUILD_CONFIG = require(process.env.BUILD_CONFIG);  
    ....
    return defaults;
}
```

So webpack is supposed to be called like `BUILD_CONFIG=some-config.js webpack`. Note that `some-config.js` contains a lot of non-webpack stuff, so I can't just return it from `main` or merge it with `defaults`

Now, I have `my-own-loader` in `my-own-loader.js`:

```
// my-own-loader.js

module.exports = function main(content) {
  ...
```

My question is how to access that `BUILD_CONFIG` variable from webpack's `main` in the loader's `main`.

Comment: I'm not super clear on where you want to use the variable, but are you trying to do something similar to what [environment variables](https://webpack.js.org/guides/environment-variables/) in WebPack accomplishes?

Comment: @zero298: yes, but how can I access it from within a loader?

Comment: Please take a look at my answer and let me know if I'm way off base on what you are asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I understand what you are trying to do and have an example project detailing the process.

To start, I'm going to set an environment variable named `TEST_VAR` through whatever mechanism my platform supports.  I'm on macOS, so that's `export TEST_VAR=fizzbuzz`.  My **loader.js** is able to use that environment variable through the node convention: `process.env.TEST_VAR`.

Remember, your `webpack.config.js` is still a node run JavaScript file.  You can use all the built-ins that node supports including `process.env`.

Consider the following files and structure:

### Structure

```
webpack-test
|- package.json
|- webpack.config.js
|- index.html
|- /dist
  |- bundle.js
|- /loaders
  | obj-loader.js
|- /res
  |- /obj
    |- dummy.obj
|- /src
  |- index.js
```

---

### package.json

```
{
  "name": "webpack-test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "webpack": "^3.8.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "http-server": "^0.10.0",
    "loader-utils": "^1.1.0",
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "http-server .",
    "build": "webpack",
  },
}
```

### webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
    },
    resolveLoader: {
        modules: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, "loaders")
        ]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.obj$/,
                use: {
                    loader: "obj-loader",
                    options: {
                        dummyText: "lorem ipsum"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

### /loaders/obj-loader.js

```
const loaderUtils = require("loader-utils"),
    schemaUtils = require("schema-utils");

function loader(source) {
    const options = loaderUtils.getOptions(this);
    console.log(options);

    let tmp = process.env.TEST_VAR;
    if (tmp === undefined) {
        console.warn("TEST_VAR is not defined");
    }
    return `export default function(){return "TEST_VAR: ${tmp} || ${source} || ${options.dummyText}";}`;
}

module.exports = loader;
```

### /res/obj/dummy.obj

```
Hello
```

### /src/index.js

```
import dummy from "../res/obj/dummy.obj";

(function () {
    "use strict";

    function main() {
        document.querySelector("p").innerHTML = dummy();
    }
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", main);
}());
```

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Webpack Test</title>
    <script src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<bod>
    <main>
        <h1>Webpack Test</h1>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    </main>
</bod>

</html>
```

---

Whenever I build and run this webpage, I get what amounts to:

```
<main>
    <h1>Webpack Test</h1>
    <p>TEST_VAR: fizzbuzz || Hello || lorem ipsum</p>
</main>
```

Where "fizzbuzz" was added from the environment variable, "Hello" the source is from `/res/obj/dummy.obj`, and "lorem ipsum" is the text that I specified as the `dummyText` option for the `obj-loader`.  However, it could have just as easily come from an environment variable that I set.

---

**Additional update based on edit**

Considering your edit, what about this; instead of setting the rule in `defaults` set it in the exported function to get scope access.  Then add your loader rules based on the new rule syntax: [`module.loaders` is now `module.rules`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#module-loaders-is-now-module-rules).  That way you have access to `options` in your custom loader and thus have access to `BUILD_CONFIG`.

### Newer webpack.config.js

```
// Hypothetically you run:
// export BUILD_CONFIG=some-config.js
// Which sets:
// process.env.BUILD_CONFIG = "some-config.js";

// New Webpack loader/rules syntax
// https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/#module-loaders-is-now-module-rules
let defaults = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            /*
             *Set this later in exported function
            {
                test: ".some.special.stuff",
                use: {
                    loader: "my-own-loader",
                    options: {
                        some: "options"
                    }
                }
            }
             */
        ]
    }
};

module.exports = function (content) {
    let BUILD_CONFIG = require(process.env.BUILD_CONFIG);    
    // Other code

    let dd = defaults;
    defaults.module.rules.push({
        test: ".some.special.stuff",
        use: {
            loader: "my-own-loader",
            options: {
                stuffFromEnvConfig: BUILD_CONFIG
            }
        }
    });

    return dd;
};
```

### my-own-loader.js

```
const loaderUtils = require("loader-utils"),
    schemaUtils = require("schema-utils");

module.exports = function main(content) {
    const options = loaderUtils.getOptions(this);
    console.log(options);

    let tmp;
    if (options.stuffFromEnvConfig.useFirst) {
        tmp = "Fizz";
    } else {
        tmp = "Buzz";
    }

    return `export default function(){return "TEST_VAR: ${tmp}";}`;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for that, unfortunately my build-time config is more than just some env variables, so I can't attach it to `process.env`.

Comment: @georg Can you go into more detail then? I’m really not clear on your configuration.

Comment: @georg OK, I took one more crack at a solution based on your edit.  This gives your loader access to the `BUILD_CONFIG` from webpack's main in your loader's main.

Comment: Yep, this looks like a viable solution. Thanks a lot!